# Query works in console and not works in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
user = User.find_by(authentication_token: params[:authentication_token])
user.update(ip: nil)
```

when i try these lines on rails console it works like a charm.
when i try it on my app, it doesn't work at all.

it releases the following error:

> undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass

Any help?

Comment: What is the output of `params`?

Comment: @Pavan   Parameters: {"authentication_token"=>"RrJqL7z7qVWbEvw5leYOyU 1filrnYj5QTMKeWOyXhPIJpGzYyJoTM4w/GgFjl4mLrdV/elztVM534N56zvObQ=="}

Comment: Try `params["authentication_token"]` instead of `params[:authentication_token]`

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Try finding the user in the console and the code with that actual value (`"RrJqL7z7qVWbEvw5leYOyU 1filrnYj5QTMKeWOyXhPIJpGzYyJoTM4w/GgFjl4mLrdV/elztVM534N56zvObQ==`"), rather than the variable. Is a user returned in both cases? A debugger like `pry-rails` might be useful here.

Comment: what's the context? is the above code in a controller? if `user` is turning out to be `nil`, then there are basically two possibilities: 1) the user with the `authentication_token` isn't in the database (app is perhaps running in a different environment from your console) or 2) the params aren't being passed to the controller correctly.

Seconding @JakeWorth's comment, you should add `byebug` or `binding.pry` to your controller (depending on what gem you have) and inspect the params from within the running controller. Alternatively you can just watch the server console for what params come in.

Comment: i have rendered params as json and returned from userscontroller, it turned out that the token is "RrJqL7z7qVWbEvw5leYOyU 1filrnYj5QTMKeWOyXhPIJpGzYyJoTM4w/GgFjl4mLrdV/elztVM534N56zvObQ=="

but the orgintal token contains a "+" in the middle "..OyU+1fil" , instead the params returns the string separated with a space, how to handle it?

Comment: I solved it replacing + sign with '%2B', and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

by some searching and debugging, i found that '+' isn't appearing in authentication token in the controller, it's replaced by a space, so i found a solution here on stackoverflow says to replace + sign with '%2B' after generating the random token.

and it worked.